# From expectation to probability in the solution of a problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

The problem is:
let ($X_n$) be r.v. with $X_n\to X$ in probability. Let |$X_n| \le C$ for a constant C > $0$ and all $\omega$.

I also proved that $P(X\le c)= 1$. Now, how does this step is justified:
$$E(|X_n - X| \mathbf1_{\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\}}) \le 2c(P{|X_n-X|>\epsilon)}$$

any help?

Comment: What information do you have about $\ X_n\ $?   The step you're asking about certainly *isn't* justified for an *arbitrary* $\ X_n\ $.  If $\ X_n = 3c + X\ $, for instance, then
$$E(|X_n - X| \mathbf1_{\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\}}) = 3\mid c\mid P{(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)}\ .$$
Also, for the step to have any hope of bring justifiable, you also need $\ c\ge 0\ $.

Comment: yes, now I'm going to provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the assumption that $P(X_n\leqslant c)=1$ is also missing. This follows from the validity (almost surely) of 
$$
\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \mathbf 1_{\{ \left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert\gt\varepsilon \}}\leqslant 2c\mathbf 1_{\{ \left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert\gt\varepsilon \}}.
$$
This is due to the fact that $$\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert X_n\right\rvert+\left\lvert X\right\rvert\leqslant c+c.$$
The fact that $\lvert X\rvert\leqslant c$ almost surely is not given, but can be deduced from the convergence in probability of $(X_n)_n$ to $X$.

Comment: I edited the question so that is more accurate. Can u explain better this ineqaulity? If both $Xn$ and X are $\le$ c, why should I take 2c? Es: $X_n = c$,   $X= -4c$ then $|X_n - X| =5c$. I'm missing something

Comment: I have edited in order to give more details.